# LINQ Query Method Parameter

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0

I have been working on trying to leverage data contained in an Access Database for the last few weeks.  I got to the point where I feel I should think how I will implement the design.

If I am not mistake one cannot use an Anonymous Type as a paramter to a method.  This leaves me wondering what the best to return the result of a LINQ query within a method is.  If you need some background information all the questions are from the last two weeks.

So this leaves me wondering someting:

Do I have to use the the **var** syntax when writting my query?  Based on the article I read here [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397678.aspx) I could in theory use my own class or in the examples listed on the page ( string, int, ect ).

This leads to me to the second part of my question:
If I were to say use the following syntax

```
IEnumerable<CustomClassHere> result = (from X in ....
where ....
**select** new CustomClassHere
{
Value = X.Field<int>("...")
}
);
```

Would I have able to return the result within a method that returns a IEnumerable?

I am willing to provide additional details, provide a more detailed code sample, if my current question is not clear.  If you have any design suggestions that involve LINQ I would appreciate hearing them.  I am looking to make this class and its interaction with the Access Database as modular as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Sample Class**

```
public class abc
{
    internal string str;
    internal int i;
}
```

---

**List Collection**

```
List<abc> List = new List<abc>();

abc Obj = new abc();
Obj.str = "1";
Obj.i = 1;
List.Add(Obj);

Obj = new abc();
Obj.str = "2";
Obj.i = 1;
List.Add(Obj);

Obj = new abc();
Obj.str = "3";
Obj.i = 1;
List.Add(Obj);
```

---

```
IEnumerable<abc> FinalList = (from lst in List select lst).ToList();
```

---

**ResultSet**

[image]

---

**Sample Reference**

[**101 LINQ SAMPLES - Very helpful to make stronghold on LINQ to Objects**](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can return an `IEnumerable<CustomClass>`.

And the first part, not, you don't have to use `var`, unless you select into an anonymous class (which you aren't doing in the example above).

Comment: OK, then you can't return an anonymous object in a type-safe way.  You can just return an object and use reflection, but that has obvious drawbacks.  If you want type safety, you'll have to create a custom class.

Comment: As an aside, using var doesn't mean the type of object isn't known.  It just saves you typing it - the compiler will replace it with the real type.  e.g. `string s = ""` and `var s = ""` are EXACTLY the same.

Comment: @Ramhound Fair enough.  I'm personally a fan of var, saves a few keystrokes and can make some refactoring easier.